# Can't get a splash screen to load

Tags: android, cordova

I'm a newbie with Cordova and app-building in general. I've managed to get a simple slideshow app working, but can't seem to get a splash screen to load no matter what I try. There seems to be a lot of conflicting info on the subject, so I've tried several things, with no success.

I'm only testing for Android right now, but do want to create an app that will work on all platforms.

My config.xml file has these in it:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

... and I've got splash screen .png files in a couple places (due to the conflicting info I've seen, trying to cover all bases): in a platforms/android/res/drawable directory (regarding this, I've seen info saying the directory should be named "drawable*", but I can't add the asterisk on my Windows machine, it's not allowed, so I don't know what to do about that); and also in a www/res/screens/android directory.

I've also got

```
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android ... >
```

statements in the config file to point to the files there.

I've tried it with the config file in the root directory and in the www directory, but that doesn't seem to make a difference. (This is another piece of conflicting info I've seen, which directory should it be in?)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you are using Cordova as your building tool (not phonegap), `<gap:*>` preferences will not work.In Nikita's answer, first line is replacement for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
```

It means files in your "platforms/android/res/drawable-port-*/drawable-land-*" folders should be only "screen.png".

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

This parameter say to app after what period of time it should hide splash screen. (in ms)

But to show splash screen you need to add to your index.html this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
      cordova.exec(null, null, "SplashScreen", "show", []);
    });
</script>
```